# Adding methods to tk.Tk and tk.Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to add 2 methods to instances of `tk.Tk` and `tk.Toplevel`. The former exists as the applications root window, where the latter is created any number of times by the user. Each `tk.Toplevel` represents a different functionality of the application and current 13 variations exist. The application is configured so that only 1 instance of each variation may be created at any time.

One approach to solving this may be to subclass both classes:

```
class RootWindow(tk.Tk):
    def method_1(self):
        ...
    def method_2(self):
        ...

class TopWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def method_1(self):
        ...
    def method_2(self):
        ...
```

Since I only wish to add 2 methods for functionality (that are identical as they use methods of these classes such as `winfo_height()`), subclassing seems overkill as well as redundant as the same code is written twice. Therefore, another method may be to use `setattr()`, but I feel like that violates the open/close principle of class design:

```
def method_1(self):
    ...
def method_2(self):
    ...

class RootWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, 'method_1', method_1)
        setattr(self, 'method_2', method_2)

class TopWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, 'method_1', method_1)
        setattr(self, 'method_2', method_2)
```

Now I've only written the methods once and modified the classes; in essence, this condenses the first method and is effectively the same.

Given that `tk.Tk` is a window, and `tk.Toplevel` is a window, is there not a way through `tkinter` where I can define a method that all "window" based widgets will have access to? This wouldn't be an issue if all windows came from a single `tkinter` class, but the root window of `tk.Tk` is different than that of `tk.Toplevel` (such as for event bindings, not necessarily visual behavior).

**Edit:**

Taking a look at @BryanOakleys solution, I find that linters really dont like this; they point at unresolved references to attributes that I know the subclasses will have access to but not the mix-in class. Consider the following:

```
class Mixin:
    def method(self):
        width = self.winfo_width()
        height = self.winfo_height()
        print(f'The window is {width} x {height}')
```

IDE linters throw the caution because `self` cannot find `winfo_width` defined. I, however, know that its going to be called by instances of classes that subclass from `tk.Tk` and `tk.Toplevel`, but misuse would lead to undefined behavior, say for example:

```
class OtherWindow(Window):
    pass

o = OtherWindow()
o.method()
# Attribute error
```

Is this problematic? The proposed solution works, but feels like its being forced to work because "I know how it will be used". An obvious solution is to type hint:

```
class Mixin:
    def method(self: Union[tk.Tk, tk.Toplevel]):
        width = self.winfo_width()
        height = self.winfo_height()
        print(f'The window is {width} x {height}')
```

Thus the linters are satisfied and the code is readable to anybody (assuming they dont need to look up `Union`). Again, is this expected behavior when using mix-in classes (never tried them)?

Comment: They way you are doing it now I believe is how it is done. You inherit from a class and then add your methods. I do not think you can add a method to all "Containers" at once without writing a class for it. You could just write a class that takes an argument of `self` and then just run the winfo on that argument.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a class `Window`, which implements method_1 and method_2. Then you could define `class RootWindow(tk.Tk, Window):` and `class TopWindow(tk.Toplevel, Window):`.

Comment: What @Kevin is suggesting is exactly how Tkinter internally makes shared methods available on objects of different types - `class Widget(BaseWidget, Pack, Place, Grid):` for example.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a mixin class. Keeping custom classes for `TopWindow` and `RootWindow` is the right solution for creating a specialization of the base `Toplevel` and `Tk` classes, and the mixin solves the problem of not wanting to repeat code.

For example:

```
class CustomMixin():
    def method_1(self):
        ...
    def method_2(self):
        ...

class TopWindow(CustomMixin, tk.Toplevel):
    pass

class RootWindow(CustomMixin, tk.Tk):
    pass
```

Comment: Hum. I used a class attribute to hold the extra methods. I have not seen this use before. Would this perform any different than what I did? This looks more readable than mine at least. I may have to use it in my own work.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: I don't think it would perform any different. I personally think it's a bit more readable.

Comment: Elegant. Does this have any benefit over using `setattr()`? In use, this implementation would resolve to `TopWindow().method_1()` which  is what `setattr()` would resolve to. However, this does avoid violation of the open/closed principle which I prefer.

Comment: I don't think there's any real benefit over readability, and that's somewhat subjective.

Comment: Readability is important! Please see my edit (bottom of OP) when you can for further clarity.

Comment: So I ran into a situation using this method I have a question on. I have a class that stores 15 list that are then being used in my frame class. Now I want to pass their values to another class for processing so can I pass all of them at once or will I have to pass each list one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Write one class that has your methods then create a class attribute in your other classes that keep an instance of your extra methods class.

Try this and let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk


class SomeExtraMethods:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window

    def size(self):
        return [self.window.winfo_width(), self.window.winfo_height()]


class RootWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.extra = SomeExtraMethods(self)
        tk.Button(self, text='Print root window size', command=self.print_size).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Open top window', command=self.open_top).pack()

    def print_size(self):
        print(self.extra.size())

    def open_top(self):
        top = TopWindow()


class TopWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.extra = SomeExtraMethods(self)
        tk.Button(self, text='Print top window size', command=self.print_size).pack()

    def print_size(self):
        print(self.extra.size())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    RootWindow().mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]